# Bitbucket reliable?

Tags: mercurial, hosting, bitbucket

I understand this question is on the edge of being acceptable for stackoverflow, but still, I feel it is worth asking.

I've started using bitbucket.org a couple of days ago, attracted by mercurial hosting, 1 free private repository, a wiki and an issue tracker. Just what I needed for my project.

I have to say, the features offered and the website's interface looks great, and I didn't have any problems with mercurial-related things so far. **However, after these couple of days I am doubting if I should move somewhere else while it still easy (I haven't advertised the wiki page yet, etc...), because I am running constantly into minor and major issues**:

- Over these few days, I've noticed a lot of site slowdowns and a couple of timeouts
- I find the wiki to be rather limited in features (apparently it is based on Creole Wiki, never heard of it before). It does not allow for, for example, right-aligning of images, borderless tables, etc. (well maybe it does, but the documentation doesn't tell)
- I've noticed some bugs in the wiki (a TOC-generation macro issue was [reported](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/bitbucket/issue/561/toc-macro-seems-broken) over a year ago, but still not fixed)
- I've tried making my wiki public by changing the settings in the Admin panel, but it doesn't work.
- some more wiki things [like inserting images is awkward, creating a new page isn't very obvious, internal linking has it's issues as well, .. ]
- the sort order in the newsfeed was wrong when I pushed a multi-commited changset
- It's very nice (and brave!) they have an publicly accessibly issue-tracker for bitbucket, but seeing a list of over 500 *open* issues (28 pages * 20 issues per page) doesn't give the impression they are taken care of as well as they could. At least some issues could have been moved to some 'will-not-consider' state. I am afraid my bug report about the private/public wiki page will still be in there within one year
- The blog has a lot of post about 'downtimes'

Now, I don't want to be too hard on the people/company running bitbucket, since it isn't clear to me whether it is practically run by a single person (in which case it is truly amazing) or a well-run company (in which case it is not :-). Perhaps they have some growing pains... It is hard for me to tell.

**So, what I am looking for here, is some experiences of other people with bitbucket, and advice if I should hold out, and wait until things improve (good chances for this?). Or not**.

Comment: This really belongs on a forum; not a Q & A site.  Great question though. Maybe Hacker News or Programming Reddit?

Comment: When I started using bitbucket a month ago, everything ran smoothly and quickly, but now, I'm in the same boat as you. I've noticed massive slowdowns, and every other (HTTP) request causes the browser tab to crash. And judging from both the user base and their public issue tracker, I'm inclined to think that bitbucket isn't going anywhere fast...

Comment: The wiki implements a wiki markup language called Creole -- this is apparently an attempt at unifying the various wiki markup languages so that people can implement this language instead of coming up with their own variant of some existing markup language. I agree that it's somewhat limited -- you should go to the Creole guys and petition them for a better language.

As for the Bitbucket blog, then I think it has many posts about downtime because that is the only kind of posts Jesper makes there.

Comment: Note that [BitBucket no longer support Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581461/6309) (August 2019).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Jesper from Bitbucket here.

We're a pretty small team. In fact, most of the time, it's mainly me who does sysadmin/coding. This leaves very little time to develop new things, and sometimes, it doesn't even allow me to keep everything running smoothly (slowdowns/short outages always happen when I sleep.)

I realize this won't work in the long run, and something needs to be done. Therefore, I have decided to hire a bunch of people, mainly developers, but also a dedicated sysadmin and 1 or 2 UI guys (to make things prettier/more functional.) I'm currently wading through applications, and there are a lot of promising applicants in there.

Wrt/ stability, I've also provisioned 2 (much) larger instances from Amazon, where we do our hosting. We're throwing more money at this. I'm migrating a bunch of users/repositories to these larger instances *today*, and immediately following this, we will focus on making things faster as well.

Comment: Jesper, I really appreciate your response and your upfront answer. The situation is a bit like I expected: growing pains and short on manpower. What is currently in place, is impressive and with an eye for detail (AFAIAC), and looks promising for the future. I feel like it is worth to bear the current issues, even though it might take a couple of months for things to settle...

Comment: What would be your answer today? Is bitbucket capable and reliable of handling corporate repos?

Comment: i have same question then seler.

Comment: As a Bitbucket user, personal and professional, I am confident in bitbucket's ability to handle critical repos.

Comment: Based on the amount of issues BitBucket have been having recently I'm going to presume it's still one person managing it all :P

Answer (score 1):

Question was asked 2010, but I think this question needs a slightly more updated answer. I've been using Bitbucket for a few months now and as far as I can tell, it is an amazing git hosting system. You are provided with an issue tracker, wiki, unlimited public/private repositories, team collaboration, etc. Also, I have not yet encountered any downtime or slowness. On top of all of this, Bitbucket has an amazing UI, making navigating through source code and branches amazingly easy.

**I would definitely recommend using this, and [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/).**

*I have not tested Bitbucket with really massive commits.*

Answer (score 0):

We have been using BitBucket HG for about six months, and I have little doubt but that we will move to a different VCS.  It merges things badly, makes mistakes on complex commits, hurts our productivity.  I don't know which parts are HG vs BitBucket, but I don't even have time to find out. Of course this is happening at the worst time, we have a do or die deliverable in two weeks.

Comment: indeed for teamwork HG was not the best solution. I am currently using sourcetree almost for a year in a team of 5 people and works like a harm! Is a very good tool and also has many updates (sigh that they are interested and of course not only that :) ) which is also atlassian's tool. If you haven't change yet VCS i believe that worth to give one more chance :).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using BitBucket for a few years 1 year at my past employer and 2 years at my present employer.

It generally works fine without any problems. However, about once a month there will be some slowness. Over this particular week there were outages spanning multiple workdays where things were slow or we were unable to push our code changes for about an hour here or there.

So to summarize, most of the time it is reliable, but occasionally, about one day a month on average it is not reliable.