# Move local Mercurial repository to Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Has anyone taken a local repo and imported it into Bitbucket?  When I go to do this, the Import page asks for a URL, but I'm working on a local computer that does not have port `8000` open to the outside world.

Can I just use some special form of a file path?

Comment: Note:  I did open up the mercurial server port just to get it to work, but in general, would prefer not to do this, if possible.

Comment: Ia there a reason why you just don't do a remote push?

Comment: aha, was not aware of it.  new to mercurial and bitbucket. thank you.

Comment: Note that [BitBucket no longer support Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57581461/6309) (August 2019).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First you need to create a repository in [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), go to `Repositories -> create repository`. Then you can choose between HTTPS or SSH.

You can customize your [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) file like this:

```
[ui]
username = Your Name <youremail@example.com>

[paths]
myproject = https://.. # The one provided by Bitbucket
```

Now you can just `push` your changes to the repository:

```
$ hg commit -m "my changes"
$ hg push myproject
```

Or `pull` changes:

```
$ hg pull -u myproject
```

The `-u` option will also update your local repository after pulling the changes. You can use this option instead of pulling and then updating your local repository. The `-u` option is the same as doing:

```
$ hg pull myproject
$ hg update
```

You may also want to take a look to the [hgignore](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) file.

Comment: Can you explain the importance of setting the myproject variable? The pushing seems to work even without it.

Comment: I created an empty HG repository on BB and then tried to push as you described but I'm getting an "abort: repository is unrelated" error. What am I missing?